# upgrade pip and error on centOS7

Tags: pip

My system is CentOS7, I install python2.7.13, and then install pip. when I install pip7.0.1, it's ok. But after I update to pip9.0.1, when I use the command pip, it runs to errors.

File "/usr/local/python2.7.13/bin/pip", line 7, in 
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 28, in 
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in 
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 36, in 
    from pip.utils.glibc import libc_ver
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/glibc.py", line 4, in 
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.13/lib/python2.7/ctypes/**init**.py", line 7, in 
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named _ctypes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add the complete error to your question.

Comment: I have added my complete error, thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by myself. I have tried install pip by get-pip.py, easy_install and source code. And easy_install was installed by setuptools. But the pip doesn't work. In the end, I install easy_install by distribute_setup.py
and then install pip by easy_install. Pip works correctly now.